# SSRS: Underlying SQL uses 'union all' -- results are much smaller set than expected -- plus better way than Tablix-filtering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, filtering, ssrs-tablix

I am using SSRS, Visual Studio 2015, with underlying TSQL.  The SSRS uses 2016/01/reportdefinition.

I need to filter on a parameter (using a tablix filter with a 'like' option) with an underlying SQL statement:

```
SELECT col1 as result1, col2 as result2 FROM table1
UNION all
SELECT colA as result1, colB as result2 FROM table 2
order by result1
```

The Tablix like statement is:

```
="*" + Parameters!Result1.Value + "*"
```

I would *assume* that the parameter would cause an underlying where clause to be applied to both the SQL statements in the above UNION all, but I don't know that for sure. [This assumption is **not** correct:  see answers below]

The SQL server for the project is SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014.

In any event, when I run the query with the where statements in SSMS [v 17.7], it is very fast and it returns 12 results.

But when I run the query in the rdl-file preview for SSRS, it is *extremely* slow.  I am therefore using a:

```
 Set Rowcount 1000
```

statement.  However, it only returns 1 result, instead of 12.  If I remove the "Set Rowcount" option, nothing usable happens, and the "Loading" message just has a spinning icon.

Does anyone have any insight how the queries are modified to filter for the parameter,and why fewer results are returned than expected?

*Possibility:*  Does it run a query without the where, limit the results to 1000, and then, depending on the ordering involved, exclude several of the potential result-matches? [This *possibility* **is** actually what happens, see answers below]

NOTE:  There is a much better way than what is asked about in the original question.  Instead of tablix-filtering, one can do the filter in the SQL where query.  See answer from OP.

Comment: As described in the answer by @alanschofield, the filter is applied after the results are retrieved. So you are actually bringing back *all* the rows, then applying your filter, which is why its so slow. When you add the RowCount, you are then saying *give me the first 1000 rows*, and then after that applying your filter in the tablix. The reason you only see one is that only 1 of your 12 rows is in the first 1000 rows of the result set.

Comment: I added a 2nd answer for a much better way than proposed in the original question. Tablix-based filters are not as efficient as needed for very large data-sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not modified at all. The dataset query runs and returns all results just the same as if you had run the query in SSMS. If you have a filter on your tablix then that filter only applies to that tablix. You could have another report item such as a tablix or a chart even pointing to the same dataset each with their own filters.

Your query could be using a bad plan, you should be able to test this easily by adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of your dataset query. This will force the plan to be recreated. Don't set the rowcount or you won't get a true test.

If your dataset query is still running slowly in SSRS, then try putting a trace on the connection using Profiler (from the SSMS tools menu) and check that the SQL being executed is what you expect.

if that doesn't help, please post the full query so it can be assessed (I'm assuming that your actual query is not what you stated in your question...)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by Alan Schofield is complete for the question, there is a better way than that in the original question.

It is by far a better alternative to match the parameter.

To do this,  one would use the following xml syntax in the appropriate place in the rdl-file:

```
<DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>MyDataSource</DataSourceName>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="@Result">
            <Value>=Parameters!Result.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
        <CommandText>
          --------------------------------------------------------------------
          use MyDataSource;
          --------------------------------------------------------------------
          select col1 as result1,  col2 as result2 from table1 a
          where  col1 LIKE '%' + @Result + '%'
          Union all
          select colA as result1,  colB as result2 from table2 b
          where  colA  LIKE '%' + @Result + '%'
          order by  result1,  
          --------------------------------------------------------------------</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
```